# Sort an array using ASCII in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I was trying to sort an array that contains a mixture of characters and numbers, like:

```
var list=[54584, NH24154, HR655, 898569, 964765, DEGF656464, 656656566...]
```

How to sort this array using ASCII code in Reactjs?
I done sorting in characters only arrays,

```
 list = _.orderBy(gridData, (o) => typeof o[event.target.id] === 'string' ? o[event.target.id].trim().toLowerCase() : o[event.target.id], order[event.target.id] ? 'asc' : 'desc');
```

But it doesn't help me in this case.

Comment: are they strings?  what have you tried?

Comment: @DavinTryon yeah...they are strings

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sort()` should order the array in-place alpha-numerically:

```js
    var list=["54584", "NH24154", "HR655", "898569", "964765", "DEGF656464", "656656566"]

    list.sort();

    console.log(list);
```

*Note: `sort` function sorts in-place and does not return the sorted array.